# Can Voracious Reader be completed with chapter select?

Tags: achievements, carto

The Voracious Reader achievement is given for reading every story in the Story Chalet. [According to TrueAchievements](https://www.trueachievements.com/a310232/voracious-reader-achievement) these stories are spread across Chapter 4, 6.1, 8.1, and 10.1.

Can I use chapter select to play the specific chapters where these books are present? Or will the achievement only count if I read every book on a single continuous playthrough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can get the Voracious Reader achievement using chapter select.

After completing the game I used chapter select to revisit chapter 4. Apparently the last book I was missing was from this chapter, as I got the achievement after re-reading The Little Cartographer after solving the puzzle but before leaving the building.